# Modify Vim section jumping with [[ and ]]?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to change [[ and ]] to jump to the nearest { or } in the first column (as it does by default), or in the first column ***after*** some number of tabs?

For example, I'd like it to work for both of these:

```
function a()
{
}
```

```
<tab><tab>*function b()
<tab><tab>*{
<tab><tab>*}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really and the doc even suggests making custom mappings, like these:

```
nnoremap ]] :call search('^\s*}', 'e')<CR>
nnoremap [[ :call search('^\s*{', 'eb')<CR>
```

See `:help search()`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding these lines to my vimrc file: `nnoremap ]] :call search('^\s*function ', '')<CR>` and `nnoremap [[ :call search('^\s*function ', 'b')<CR>`

Comment: Update: the maps in my previous comment work ok, but vim doesn't remember the previous position with the `''` command. I found that the `CustomJump()` function in the following comment fixed the problem, so I call it now instead of `search()`: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6074/23234